# Create a priority based round robin algorithm

Tags: algorithm, round-robin, preemption

In this question I want to develop a Priority Based Round Robin algorithm for schedule some tasks.

```
This is the input tasks
AT = Arrival Time
BT = Burst Time
P  = Priority



Process  AT BT P
 1       0  8  5
 2       1  4  1
 3       2  9  4
 4       3  5  3
```

And the desired output is

```
Process Start End
1       0     1
2       1     5
4       5     10
1       10    17
3       17    26
```

Is there any proper algorithm to schedule this? it is able to use data structures like Queue etc.

I tried using 2 `PriorityQueues` and could not be success
This is done in JAVA, but it ends with most of doing nothing.

```
public static void scheduleRoundRobin(int q, ArrayList<CPUProcess> processes){
    processes.sort(new ArrivalTimeSorter());
    int t = processes.get(0).getArriveTime();
    PriorityQueue<CPUProcess> idleQ = new PriorityQueue<>(new BurstComparator());
    PriorityQueue<CPUProcess> readyQ = new PriorityQueue<>(new PriorityComparator());
    ArrayList<CPUProcess> results = new ArrayList<>();
    CPUProcess currentJob = null;

    while (processes.size() > 0 || readyQ.size() > 0 || idleQ.size() > 0){
        for (CPUProcess process : processes){
            if (!process.isFinished() && process.getArriveTime() <= t){
                if (currentJob == null){
                    currentJob = process;
                    currentJob.setStartTime(t);
                }
                else
                    readyQ.add(process);
            }
        }


        if (currentJob != null){
            if (readyQ.peek() != null){
                CPUProcess process = readyQ.peek();
                if (process.getPriority() < currentJob.getPriority() && process.getBrustTime() < currentJob.getBrustTime()){
                    currentJob.setEndTime(t);
                    idleQ.add(currentJob);
                    results.add(CPUProcess.getClone(currentJob));
                    currentJob = process;
                }
            }

                else if (idleQ.peek() != null){
                    if (currentJob.getBrustTime() <= 0){
                        results.add(CPUProcess.getClone(currentJob));
                        processes.remove(currentJob);
                    }
                    currentJob = idleQ.peek();
                    idleQ.remove();
                }

        }

        if (currentJob != null){
            currentJob.setBrustTime(currentJob.getBrustTime() - t);
        }

        t += q;
    }

    System.out.println(results);
}
```

Here are the interfaces i ve implemented

```
class PriorityComparator implements Comparator<CPUProcess>{
    @Override
    public int compare(CPUProcess o1, CPUProcess o2) {
      return o1.getPriority() - o2.getPriority();
    }
}

class ArrivalTimeSorter implements Comparator<CPUProcess>{

    @Override
    public int compare(CPUProcess o1, CPUProcess o2) {
        return o1.getArriveTime() - o2.getArriveTime();
    }
}

class BurstComparator implements Comparator<CPUProcess>{

    @Override
    public int compare(CPUProcess o1, CPUProcess o2) {
        return o1.getBrustTime() - o2.getBrustTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: "it ends with most of doing nothing" is not a sufficient problem specification.  Include the output you did get, your debugging trace, etc.

Comment: it just prints the task 1, nothing else

Comment: despite the code i tried, i would like to know whether there is a proper way to tackle this problem

Comment: How is this a round robin problem?  In your desired output, the process executing at any given time is the one with the lowest priority number.

Comment: Lowest number is typically concerned as highest priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic algorithm is a simple simulation.  You put your processes in an arrival queue, sorted by arrival time (just as you show).  Then you simulate the scheduler, iterating through time.  At each time step

- Ingest: any process arriving at this time, move from the arrival queue to the execution list, inserting it according to priority.
- Schedule: choose the process with the highest priority.
- Execute: decrement the remaining execution (burst) time for that process.  If the result is 0, remove the process from the execution list.

Continue this until the arrival queue and execution list are empty.

Comment: let me give a shot

Comment: As you can see, in the output it does not just only selects by the priority

Comment: You did?  I don't see it on your questions list.  I was going to try to help again ...